# Tips for Beginner with PyQt5 and UTF8

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8, pyqt5

I am learning to build GUIs using **PyQt5** (on Windows).
I came accross a piece of code with explicit translation into UTF8 in **PyQt4** (not PyQt5):

```
a=QApplication(args)
button=QPushButton(a.trUtf8("éàùè"),None)
```

After a little bit of googling I found that `trUtf8` is deprecated and that now Qt5 assumes that your code is already UTF8 formatted ([link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html)):

```
QObject::trUtf8() and QCoreApplication::Encoding are deprecated. Qt assumes that the source code is encoded in UTF-8.
```

So, I'd like to know what I should do to comply with this statement.

Even if I am not looking for a vim oriented solution, I'd like to add that I am using Vim to develop my code. So, I added the following options to my setup:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

Is it correct, is it enough?
More generally, what do you need to be UTF8 compliant with Qt5?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested if it works?

Comment: Yes it is working on my PC I can display "é" on my GUI for example. But how can I be sure it would work on different PC/OS? I mean my OS is probably configured to display those characteres correctly by default.
I don't know how it is working that is why I am asking. And I don't want to just "make it work", I am looking for a robust solution :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tr`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#tr) function has nothing to do with encoding/decoding *per se* - it is used for marking out which literal strings may require translation in applications which support multiple languages (if you're familiar with [gnu gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), it performs a similar role to the `_()` function).

Strings which are marked for translation will only get translated if a [translator](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtranslator.html) is installed. Otherwise, the strings will be passed through unchanged. The encoding/decoding aspect only comes into play because the C++ functions take in the source strings as `const char*` (i.e. bytes) and return a `QString` (i.e. unicode). So if there is no translation available, and the source string contains non-ASCII characters, a default decoding step would need to be performed. In Qt4, this had to be done explicitly with `trUtf8` under some circumstances (see [the docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#trUtf8) for details) - but in Qt5 it can all handled by the `tr` function alone.

If you're using Python 3 with PyQt5, you can pretty much forget about all these issues, because literal strings are unicode by default, and UTF-8 is assumed as the source-code encoding. Also, PyQt5 will always return a python unicode object for any Qt function that would normally return a `QString`.

And of course, if you never intend to support multiple languages in your application, you can safely omit all usage of `tr`, as it would otherwise perform no useful function.

Comment: Such a detailed answer! Thank you so much. I have another question: if someday I want to use Qt with C++, would it be the same? In other words: is it thanks to Python3 and PyQt that I can forget about string encoding? Thanks again!

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say you can forget about string encoding *in general* - but you can probably forget about any issues there may have been with the use of `tr/trUtf8`. Having said that, Python3 + PyQt5, should be a very unicode-friendly combination. The more general problems with encodings won't go away until all the legacy encodings go away (which won't happen in our lifetimes). So it doesn't really matter what language/toolkit you use - if your application takes in data as bytes, you will always have to deal with the issue of encodings.